# DOM Удалить при 10 елементах

Tags: javascript

```
var counter = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("bid");

  button.onclick = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = "Item";
    list.appendChild(item);
    var body = document.getElementById("list").childNodes;
    counter++;
    if (counter == 10) {
      for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
        body.splice(i, 1);
      }
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Есть кнопка при нажатии создает `li` в `ul`.

> ***body.splice is not a function***  Вот такую ошибку выдает браузер.

И это далеко не первая попытка переписать эту часть. Помогите задать условие чтобы при `counter = 10` удалять все `li`.

`body = Nodelist [li,li,...]`

Comment: А вы body выводили в консоль, это точно массив? Добавьте этот момент в вопрос, а также dom-дерево. На первый взгляд все ок

Comment: `childNodes` возвращает коллекцию DOM элементов, это НЕ массив, соответственно у неё не такие же методы, как у массива и метода `splice` у неё нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У типа `NodeList` действительно [нет такой функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

```
if (counter == 10) {
  list.innerHTML = "";
  counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: При таком условии counter обнуляет а списки можно дальше добавлять >10

Comment: Извините, мозги немного кипят. Вы все правильно написали. Убрал .childNodes написал условие и все работает. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @iWantBeDeveloper На здоровье. Успехов!